# Sort compare function does nothing. Won't even print to Log or Error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have this reducer I am working on that takes in some json feeds of some post objects form an established set of endpoints and loads items them into an array. So far all is good the items load into the array just fine and I can access them. The issue I am having is seeing as the posts come from different sources I need to sort them by date to ensure they are presented in the correct order so I wrote a little anonymous sort compare function that should be able to calculate the time difference and sort accordingly. Problem is the compare function seems to not even be called as it won't even output to the console.

I have tried fat arrow functions as well and that also doesn't seem to help.

```
const postReducer = (state = {
    news: [],
    sources: ["posts/feed1", "posts/feed2"]
}, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case "UPDATE_NEWS":
            state.news = [];
            state.sources.map((source) => {
                fetch(source)
                    .then(res => res.json())
                    .then(
                        (result) => {
                            result.feed.map((item) => {
                                state.news.push(item)
                                }
                            );
                        },
                        (error) => {
                            console.error("Failed to load post stream at " + source)
                        }
                    );
            });

            // Problem starts here
            let sorted = state.news; 
            sorted.sort(function(a,b){
                // Code here seems to do nothing
                let value = moment(a.dateTime).valueOf() - moment(b.dateTime).valueOf();
                console.error("comparing " + a.dateTime + " vs " + b.dateTime + " with value " + value);
                return value;
            });
            console.log(sorted == state.news); // Always outputs true
            break;
    }
    return state;
};
```

Expected: Sort compare function does something.
Actual Results: Sort compare function does absolutely nothing.

Comment: sort mutates the array. by assigning an array, both references are sorted and have the same object reference.

Comment: @NinaScholz I figured as much I was just playing around trying to see if some how reassigning the variable somehow made a difference. Even removing sorted = from the front of that line doesn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was likely caused by the asynchronous code not returning the result till after the sorted function has ran. this means when it try's to perform the sort there is nothing to sort.

To solved it I implemented thunk as a middle ware to handle asynchronous actions and using ES6 promises to perform any operations on the data.

This video and series was insanely helpful:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h892pHdLQtM